# Create IP cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I'm looking for a code to create an IP cookie. I want to retrieve the IP adress from the visitor, and then store it. If the same user visits the website again, he should receive a message like "welcome back!". Thanks in advance.

Comment: That should be stored as a session variable, not cookie. It would be too easy to spoof it as a client side cookie

Comment: And you retrieve it and then on second visit compare the second visit IP to what?

Comment: Why don't you just store a cookie and on the second visit just check if the cookie exists and then show the welcome back message ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing the IP in a cookie just use the remote_addr variable in PHP server-side, like so:

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // echo's the user's IP address
```

Then use a Database for example to store every visitor in a table, then check the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` for any occurrences in the table

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And how would I combine this with HTML? The thing is, I'm making such a line on a website that sais "This website uses cookies." Next to  this line then is a button which sais "Cookies are OK". When a user presses this button, the cookie should be activated. Then, when the user comes to the website again, they should get the message "welcome back!". Could you maybe give me more complete code for this?

Comment: *"Could you maybe give me the complete code for this"* that's not what this site is for...